# python v 2.7.13 with twilio v 6.5.2 cannot find module named urllib3 when importing Client

Tags: python, twilio

I'm using python version 2.7.13 and twilio version 6.5.2 and I'm trying the simple example from twilio website which begins with

```
from twilio.rest import Client
```

then goes on to send a text message to a phone number. Executing that first line within idle produces this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\send_text.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import Client
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twilio\http\http_client.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

I have found similar questions in this forum but the details are slightly different and the solutions do not apply to my situation.

Comment: `pip install urllib3` ?

Answer (score 2):

**First**, check this link: https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/

**Second**, on your console, execute: `pip install urllib3`

This steps maybe can help you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you.  I will reinstall using pip rather than easy_install

Comment: By the way,  https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/ is dead.  But, it was easy to Google search for "How to install pip on Windows 7".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the module using `pip install urllib3` before you import it.

Comment: Thank you.  I will reinstall using pip rather than easy_install

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Jose Moreno and Colin Ricardo.
Re-installing twilio using pip rather than easy_install was step one.  Then, as suggested by Jose and Colin, the next step was to pip install urrlib3.
Turned out to be two more things that were missing, but pip installing them worked.
Then I was able to get a trial phone number from twilio and their sample send_text.py program actually worked for me!